# How could avoid blank spaces to be saved to the DB?

Tags: php, jquery, database, validation

I've been trying to save some input to a DB using jquery. I'd like to prevent the user filling the DB with blank spaces. The code I've done so far doesn't allow to continue if the customer leaves the input box blank, which is ok. The thing is, if the customer hits the space bar more than once the record will be saved to the database. Bottom line is... I'd like to let the user keep going ONLY when he's written something into the input box. Sorry for my grammar. Hope you guys can understand. Thank you so much!

Here's the script I'm using ATM:

```
            <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(function() 
            {
                $('.btn-det').click(function(e) 
                {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var name = $('#name').val();
                    var surname = $('#surname').val();

                    if (name === "" && surname === "") 
                    {
                        alert("Please, enter your details!");
                        $("#userQuestion").hide();
                    }
                    else if(name != "" && surname === "") 
                    {
                        alert("Please, enter your Surname");
                        $("#userQuestion").hide();
                    }
                    else if(name === "" && surname != "") 
                    {
                        alert("Please, enter your Name");
                        $("#userQuestion").hide();
                    }
                    else {
                        $.post("saveDetails.php", 
                        { 
                            name: name,
                            surname: surname 
                        });

                        $("#userDetails").hide(500);
                        $("#userQuestion").show(600);
                    }   
                });
            });
        }); 
    </script>
```

I forgot to mention that, before saving to the DB, I have the following function which uses .trim() but it does not delete white space. It deletes only spaces at the begining and end of whatever the input is. Thanks again!

```
            function test_input($data)
    {

        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripcslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);

        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: Use `Jquery.trim` on client and `trim` on server.

Comment: You could check strings in javascript with `variable.trim() !== ""` which will remove spaces. Remember that you always need to enforce all rules on the server side as well. Client side (browser + js) validation is for the user only.

Comment: You should worry more about cleaning/validation from your server, not the client. I can easily bypass anything you do there.

Comment: @JuanM Did my anwser help you?

Comment: Sorry lads. Maybe I didn't explain myself clearly. I don't want to eliminate spaces after saving to DB. What I'm trying to do is not to let the user to enter white spaces at all. I do not want to allow it. I know what you guys mean about server side validation but, as this is just a personal experiment, I will not worry about that ATM. If anyone could give me a hand here, it would be very much appreciated! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys. This is what I did. Instead of using just an "else", I used an "else if" with the condition that none of the input fields are blank, and trimmed those at the same time... Here's just the piece I edited:

Thanks a lot for your help!

```
    if (name === "" && surname === "") 
                    {
                        alert("Please, enter your details!");
                        $("#userQuestion").hide();
                    }
                    else if(name !== "" && surname === "") 
                    {
                        alert("Please, enter your Surname");
                        $("#userQuestion").hide();
                    }
                    else if(name === "" && surname !== "") 
                    {
                        alert("Please, enter your Name");
                        $("#userQuestion").hide();
                    }

                    //If there's any data saved into the variables, it deletes any leading and trailing white spaces//
                    else if($.trim(name) != "" && $.trim(surname) != "")
                    {

                        $.post("saveDetails.php", 
                        { 
                            name: name,
                            surname: surname 
                        });

                        $("#userDetails").hide(500);
                        $("#userQuestion").show(600);
```

Again, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can use the trim function on a string before sending the data :

```
var name = $('#name').val();
name = name.trim();
```

> http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp

This will remove the blank spaces before and after the string

In php you can do the same

```
$name = trim((string) $_POST['name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, TRIM by default only remove spaces (not all whitespaces). [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) is the doc.

```
UPDATE FOO set FIELD2 = TRIM(FIELD2);
```

> http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp

**If you need to use trim in select query, you can also use regular expressions**

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE field RLIKE ' * query-string *'
```

> MySql Resouces

Another Example:

```
UPDATE student_surveys
SET favorite_activities =
TRIM(LEADING SPACE(1) FROM TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM favorite_activities));
```

Answer (score 0):

use following function

```
trim($data," \t")
```

this will remove whitespaces and tabs from the beginning and end of a string.
Have a look at

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

you have to give " " as second parameter which means that remove
whitespace (i.e " ") beginning and end of a string and "\t" means remove tab. Combining both (i.e " \t") means remove space and tab.